# Logging error in Python 3.x : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, byte

I am on Python 3.6.5.

While using logging I am getting the following error -

"TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

It worked fine in Python 2.x and also I tried converting the string to Byte object but could not fix the problem

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config_file = '/source/account_content_recommendation/config/sales_central_config.json'
    try:
        ### Read all the parameters -
        params = json.loads(hdfs.read_file(config_file))

        ### Create the logging csv file -
        hdfs_log_path = params["hdfs_log_path"]
        hdfs.create_file(hdfs_log_path, "starting ... ", overwrite = True)
        log_name = 'Account_Content_Matching'


        global stream
        log = logging.getLogger('Acct_Cont_Log')
        stream = BytesIO()
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        for handle in log.handlers:
            log.removeHandler(handle)

        log.addHandler(handler)

        #env = sys.argv[1]
        env = 'dev'
        formatter = logging.Formatter('{0}| %(asctime)s| {1}| %(module)s| %(funcName)s| %(lineno)d| %(levelname)s| %(message)r'.format(log_name, env))
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        log.info("starting execution of Account_Content_Matching load")
        #log.info("sys args %s"%(str(sys.argv)))

        def flush_log():
            global stream
            msg = stream.getvalue()
            hdfs.append_file(hdfs_log_path, msg)
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate(0)
            print(msg)
            sys.stdout.flush

    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

I am getting the below error -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/logging/**init**.py", line 994, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Also ...

Message: 'starting execution of Account_Content_Matching load'
Arguments: ()
I1001 06:29:35.870266 140241833649984 :29] starting execution of Account_Content_Matching load

Comment: Either use *TextIO* or prefix all the strings that you log with a b (e.g. `b"bytes-string"`), or use encode: `"string".encode()`.

Comment: Thanks Cristi, as you said, I converted that to a StringIO and that solved the problem. This is what I did -
from io import StringIO ;
stream = StringIO()

Comment: Allright!, I'll post an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your logger setup, you're:

- Using *BytesIO* as a stream
- Passing strings to it

This doesn't work, the 2 must be in *sync*. There are 2 ways to fix it. **Either**:

- Use [[Python.Docs]: class io.StringIO(initial_value='', newline='\n')](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO) (instead of *BytesIO*):

  ```py
  stream = StringIO()
  ```
- Convert all strings to *bytes* before passing them to the logger methods (more complicated, and makes less sense than the former):

  ```py
  log.info("starting execution of Account_Content_Matching load".encode())  # log.info(b"starting execution of Account_Content_Matching load")  # For literals
  log.debug(some_string_var.encode())
  ```